# Authenticating an Azure AD token in WebApi

Tags: azure-active-directory

We are building a webAPI service that customers will hit using AAD tokens. So this service needs to Authenticate the token to make sure it’s valid.
This is a multi-tenant scenario.

I went through AAD docs and have few questions. It would be greatly appreciated if someone can help answer them.

1)  Based on my understanding, the service will download the public signing tokens from AAD and caches them. These are used to validate the token, is that correct?

2)  What’s the recommended interval to refresh the cached signing tokens? also, the recommendation around on-demand refresh in-case AAD rotates the keys within the refresh period?

3)  Per AAD sample code I found at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/active-directory-signing-key-rollover

```
MetadataSerializer serializer = new MetadataSerializer()
                {
                    // Do not disable for production code
                    CertificateValidationMode = X509CertificateValidationMode.None
                };
```

Turning on validation of the cert doesn’t work since the machine doesn’t trust the AAD root cert, what’s the recommendation here? Do we need to manually install a cert in our trusted store?

4)  In AAD sample code @ https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/active-directory-signing-key-rollover, it’s downloading those signing tokens in synchronous way, is there an async version of the code?

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK, the request will get the tokens issued by Azure AD which sign by the private key. And the web API will verify the tokens using the public key from [key endpoints](https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/discovery/keys) of Azure AD automatically(OWIN component).

And to developer a web API using version after Visual Studio 2013, there is no need to verify the token manually. Here is a piece of code to protect the web API:

```
public void ConfigureAuth(IAppBuilder app)
{
    app.UseWindowsAzureActiveDirectoryBearerAuthentication(
        new WindowsAzureActiveDirectoryBearerAuthenticationOptions
        {
            Audience = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ida:Audience"],
            Tenant = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ida:Tenant"],
            TokenValidationParameters = new System.IdentityModel.Tokens.TokenValidationParameters() { ValidateIssuer = false }
        });
}
```

[Here](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-dotnet-webapi-multitenant-windows-store) is the link for the full code sample protecting the web API for the multi-tenant.

### Update(support password and token authentication for different controllers)

```
public void ConfigureAuth(IAppBuilder app)
        {
            app.UseWindowsAzureActiveDirectoryBearerAuthentication(
                new WindowsAzureActiveDirectoryBearerAuthenticationOptions
                {
                    Audience = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ida:Audience"],
                    Tenant = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ida:Tenant"],
                    TokenValidationParameters = new System.IdentityModel.Tokens.TokenValidationParameters() { ValidateIssuer = false }
                });

            app.UsePasswordAuthentication();
        }

public class PasswordAuthorization : AuthorizeAttribute
{
    public override void OnAuthorization(HttpActionContext actionContext)
    {
        var principal = actionContext.RequestContext.Principal as ClaimsPrincipal;

        if (principal.FindFirst("authenticationType") == null)
        {
            actionContext.Response = new HttpResponseMessage
            {
                StatusCode = HttpStatusCode.Unauthorized,
                Content = new StringContent("You are unauthorized to access this resource!")
            };

        }

    }
}

public class TokenAuthorization : AuthorizeAttribute
{

    public override void OnAuthorization(HttpActionContext actionContext)
    {
        var principal = actionContext.RequestContext.Principal as ClaimsPrincipal;

        if (principal.FindFirst("authenticationType") != null)
        {
            actionContext.Response = new HttpResponseMessage
            {
                StatusCode = HttpStatusCode.Unauthorized,
                Content = new StringContent("You are unauthorized to access this resource!")
            };

        }

    }
}


public class PasswordAuthenticationOptions : AuthenticationOptions
{
    public PasswordAuthenticationOptions() : base("password")
    { }
}

public class PasswordAuthenticationHandler : AuthenticationHandler<PasswordAuthenticationOptions>
{
    protected override async Task<AuthenticationTicket> AuthenticateCoreAsync()
    {
        bool authorized = await Task<bool>.Run(() => IsAuthorised(Request.Headers));
        if (authorized)
        {
            AuthenticationProperties authProperties = new AuthenticationProperties();
            authProperties.IssuedUtc = DateTime.UtcNow;
            authProperties.ExpiresUtc = DateTime.UtcNow.AddDays(1);
            authProperties.AllowRefresh = true;
            authProperties.IsPersistent = true;
            IList<Claim> claimCollection = new List<Claim>
            {
                new Claim(ClaimTypes.Name, "Andras")
                , new Claim(ClaimTypes.Country, "Sweden")
                , new Claim(ClaimTypes.Gender, "M")
                , new Claim(ClaimTypes.Surname, "Nemes")
                , new Claim(ClaimTypes.Email, "hello@me.com")
                , new Claim(ClaimTypes.Role, "IT")
                , new Claim("authenticationType", "password")
            };
            ClaimsIdentity claimsIdentity = new ClaimsIdentity(claimCollection, "Custom");
            AuthenticationTicket ticket = new AuthenticationTicket(claimsIdentity, authProperties);
            return ticket;
        }

        return null;
    }

    private bool IsAuthorised(IHeaderDictionary requestHeaders)
    {
        string[] username,password;
        bool usernamePresent = requestHeaders.TryGetValue("username", out username);
        bool passwordPresent = requestHeaders.TryGetValue("password", out password);

        if (usernamePresent& passwordPresent)
        {
            if("user1".Equals(username[0])&&"pass".Equals(password[0]))
                return true;
        }

        return false;
    }
}


public class PasswordAuthMiddleware : AuthenticationMiddleware<PasswordAuthenticationOptions>
{
    public PasswordAuthMiddleware(OwinMiddleware nextMiddleware, PasswordAuthenticationOptions authOptions)
        : base(nextMiddleware, authOptions)
    { }

    protected override AuthenticationHandler<PasswordAuthenticationOptions> CreateHandler()
    {
        return new PasswordAuthenticationHandler();
    }
}

public static class PassworAuthenticationExtension
{
    public static void UsePasswordAuthentication(this IAppBuilder appBuilder)
    {
        appBuilder.Use<PasswordAuthMiddleware>(new PasswordAuthenticationOptions());
    }
}
```

API controller using password for authentication:

```
[PasswordAuthorization]
public class Values2Controller : ApiController
{
    // GET: api/Values2
    public IEnumerable<string> Get()
    {
        return new string[] { "value1", "value2" };
    } 
}
```

API controller using AAD for authentication:

```
[TokenAuthorization]
public class ValuesController : ApiController
{ 
    // GET api/values
    public IEnumerable<string> Get()
    {
        return new string[] { "value1", "value2" };
    }
}
```

### Update(limit the tenants)

```
app.UseWindowsAzureActiveDirectoryBearerAuthentication(
new WindowsAzureActiveDirectoryBearerAuthenticationOptions
{
    Audience = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ida:Audience"],
    Tenant = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ida:Tenant"],
    TokenValidationParameters = new System.IdentityModel.Tokens.TokenValidationParameters() {
        ValidateIssuer = true,
        ValidIssuers =new string[] { "https://sts.windows.net/{tenantId}/" } 
    }
});
```

Comment: Thanks Fei. Unfortunately, I think I have to use manual verification. For instance, I want to support multiple issuer tenants. Also, I'm only validating the token for certain controller actions, for others, I have different auth model.

Comment: The code above does support the multiple-tenants. And based on my understanding, if you want to protect the web API with multiple authentication middle-ware, it should be right. However, no matter which way users use to pass the authentication, the web API will return the result.

Comment: And if you want to separate the different API using corresponding authentication(more like 'role' management, the users from different IDP has different roles), we can develop the custom attribute to verify the **specific claim** to distinguish the request from. I also update the post to append a code sample to demonstrate this scenario.

Comment: Or a more easy way is developing two web API controller for different authentication.

Comment: Thanks Fei for the code sample. When initializing WindowsAzureActiveDirectoryBearerAuthenticationOptions, you pass the tenant id that issued the token. In my case, customers can belong to different tenants, so the issuer will be different no? How can I support this?

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.owin.security.activedirectory.windowsazureactivedirectorybearerauthenticationoptions.tenant(v=vs.113).aspx#P:Microsoft.Owin.Security.ActiveDirectory.WindowsAzureActiveDirectoryBearerAuthenticationOptions.Tenant

Comment: The code above will not check the issue in the token, it means all the tenant can call this web API if they acquire the token. If you want to limit the specific tenants we can pass the `ValidIssuers`. I also update the code for check the tenants.

Comment: @GeorgeMoussa Please feel free to let me know if you still have the problem.